# Struts2 upload file error

Tags: file-upload, configuration, struts2, struts2-interceptors, interceptorstack

I want to upload a file to my web project, but I'm getting:

> WARN o.a.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher - **Could not find create multipart save directory '/temp'**.
>       WARN o.a.s.d.m.JakartaMultiPartRequest - **Unable to parse request**
>       org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: 
>       Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. 
>       `/temp/upload_1e39874d_effe_405b_9a92_3050ca60a661_00000000.tmp` **(No such file or directory)**

so I want to change the upload directory

```xml
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.multipart.saveDir" value="/tmp"></constant>
    <package name="brand-struts" extends="abstract-struts">
<action name="saveBatchBrandGoodsInfo" class="brandgoodsAction" 
                                      method="saveBatchBrandGoodsInfo">
            <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">             
                <param name="savePath">/upload</param>  
                <param name="maximumSize">1024000</param>  
            </interceptor-ref> 
            <result name="data" type="json">
                <param name="root">data</param>
            </result>
        </action>
    </package>

</struts>
```

but it doesn't work, I keep getting the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. AFAIK, there's no such thing as an `abstract-struts` package. Just extend `struts-default` and remove the `savePath` customization.
2. You're including only the **fileUpload** Interceptor, not the whole **defaultStack**. You need to do:

   ```xml
   <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack">
       <param name="fileUpload.maximumSize">1024000</param>  
   </interceptor-ref>
   ```

Also ensure your form has `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.